# Rails 6: "Unable to autoload constant" error with POST request to nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Description:

I'm using Rails 6 for my application, and I've encountered an issue when making a POST request to a nested controller. Specifically, when I try to submit a POST request to localhost:3000/api/aspr/assessment_projects with some dummy params like `{"title":"test"}`, Rails raises an error: `Unable to autoload constant Assessment, expected /home/wm/app_name/app/models/aspr/assessment.rb to define it.` However, the model is already there.

Controller Structure:

```
app/controllers/api/aspr/assessments_controller.rb
```

Model Structure:

```
app/models/aspr/assessment.rb
```

I've confirmed that all GET requests to controllers are working correctly, but the error arises only with POST requests. I suspect there might be an issue with the autoloading of the Assessment model. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the POST request works as expected?

Any help or guidance on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does your `app/models/aspr/assessment.rb` file define the `Aspr::Assessment` model? You haven't posted the contents of the described file. A detailed explanation of autoloading can be found here: [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)

Comment: Please add the code from the top of the assessment model file to question.